# Blank pie-chart with pivot table

Tags: excel, pie-chart, pivot-chart

I am trying to create a pie chart from some pivot table data but it is just appearing blank.

Pivot table data:

[image]

What my pie chart shows:

[image: Graph example]

It works ok in other slides so im unsure as to what the issue is. Any help would be great, thanks

Comment: Are you able to see uploaded pictures? Couse I can't....

Comment: @KresimirL. sorry, its not working for me either. dont know why

Comment: Thank you, It must be connected with site then, Because I'm also unable to post pictures...

Comment: @KresimirL. ok, have you by any chance got any idea what my issue is?

Comment: unfortunately no ...